ResourceTransformer called once
Is possible to ResourceTransformer will be called more then once for requested resource (for example index.html) ? CacheControl.noCache() doesn't make difference.
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        ResourceTransformer transformer = new IndexTransformer();

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addTransformer(transformer);
    }

}

public class IndexTransformer implements ResourceTransformer {

    public Resource transform(HttpServletRequest request, Resource resource, ResourceTransformerChain transformerChain) throws IOException {
        log.info(IndexTransformer.class.getName());
        log.info(resource.getFilename());
        return resource;
    }

}

